The Fraud Deposit Model run hit Banno API call errors, received an error that requests are not authorized. Please advise why?
The Fraud Deposit Model run hit Banno API call errors, we received an error that requests are not authorized on 09.18.2024. Please advise why? Were there any changes to Banno API?
The error happened in the morning on the 18th, then again when we manually tried that same afternoon. I opened a JH case with Banno support and engineers looked into the error but advised to post to this instead. This is a weekly pull and would like to know why we received the error.

Could you provide an x-request-id for this and dates/times for those requests?

`````Return 401, and give error message "Unauthorized" after a few calls. 
error when loading json, pid: ******************, will retry, resp.text: Unauth

It was just tried again, and see above information if it helps to find the cause.

@Sam please see above responses

Sorry I missed your previous comment -it looks like your message got cut off. Do you have just the x-request-id for that? It can be found in your error response

I have a pid, and I don't know what x-request-id is. This is one of the pid: 9e8e6ed2-d973-4bdc-b065-a69c7b388aa9

To Sam's point, the x-request-id is in the response headers from Banno. That helps look up API failures. In this case, though, if you got HTTP 401 Unauthorized that means your software has not presented the Access Token (or presented an incorrect token, or even an expired token). That's a situation where the x-request-id will help a lot for Sam to debug.

Our team was provided a work around that is currently working for us. I will ask a new question if we have any further issues. Thank you.
